Cannot establish connection to SQL Server using pyodbc
Cannot establish connection to SQL Server using pyodbc on Windows. Here are the steps I use:
import pyodbc as odbc

import pandas as pd

cnxn=odbc.connect(cnxn_str)

in the last step it shows this error
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 cnxn=odbc.connect(cnxn_str)

OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].  (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1)')


I've writen the server name right, and checked about Port 1433.
Please help.

Can you also show us how the connection string looks like? Make sure you don't insert any sensitive data. I'm just curious about the structure. That's little detail you provided here. 90% sure there's a problem with your connection string.

Take a look on how the connection string needs to look like and how you can easily set it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16. There's a whole tutorial on Microsoft's official website for connecting Python to SQL Server through pyodbc.

The Error Locating Server/Instance Specified in the error message suggests that you are including an instance name in the connection string. Instance name resolution requires that the SQL Browser service is running and accessible through firewalls via udp/1434. Also be aware that if you're trying to connect to SQL Server for Linux (and thus Docker containers) they do not even have an SQL Browser service.
